# Interconnect a Kubernetes cluster with a Docker network

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes

I am trying to enable communication between Kubernetes (K8s) pods and a Docker container but I cannot find how to do so on Windows. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Scenario description:

The n K8s pods are composed of one (and only) container: a Go microservice accessed by Postman at this time, itself supposed to access a database.

To enable a load-balanced access to the pods as one, a Kubernetes service is put on top, using a NodePort. So far everything is working.

But the K8s-Pod/Go-microservice <> Docker-container/db part do not see each other. The Go microservice obviously says the "db" cannot be resolved. The container db is itself in a user-defined docker network (called "mynw"); its type is a bridge.

Would anyone know how to acheive this in the simplest way? (I mean without third-party/tierce things, heavy proxy configuration, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a headless service in k8s, with an endpoint pointing to your database container. Then you have to direct your Go service to use that headless service as the db connection.

Comment: Your suggestion was the clue to the success. Many thanks!

Comment: To share with others a more detailed explanation on how to do it:
1. Deploy your K8s microservice
2. Expose it with a K8s Service
3. Build a Service said Headless because it does not refer to any pods ; it has the particularity to be `spec.type: ClusterIP` and to have `spec.clusterIP: None` so no IP address out of the box ; mind the ports
4. Build an Endpoint with ip address and port of the docker container.

To get this IP, do a `docker container inspect` on your database container.
And voilà!

Answer (score 1):

On top of [headless services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) mentioned by bserdar, you can also use services of [type externalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) if your database has a proper DNS name.

Comment: It has not but thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a look for my personal knowledge! Thanks.